# Generar tablas con valores predefinidos php7

Tags: php, formularios, revisión-de-código, depuración

Necesito hacer un script en PHP7 que genere una tabla de 10x10 y que en la diagonal esté formada por unos y el resto por ceros. Me he documientado y [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391256/generate-html-table-with-variable-rows-and-cells) describe cómo sacarlo de una base de datos, sin embargo no sé como darle los valores de la diagonal ni los 0 por defecto.
El **PHP:**

```
<?php
$end=10; 
$rows=ceil($end/8);
$x=0;
$start=0;
?>
<table>
<?php
while($x<=$rows) {
  echo "<tr>";
  for ($y = 0; $y < 8; $y++, $start++) {
    if ($start <= $end) echo "<td>$start</td>";
  }
  echo "</tr>";
  $x++;
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado o que idea tienes? El código que pones simplemente lo tomaste de la respuesta de StackOverflow en inglés.

Comment: He intentado modificar los valores de las variables para obtener un cuadrado con números random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usar dos ciclos  Repetitivos `for` , y para la impresión de si será `1` o `0` un `if` mediante operador ternario [ternary-operators](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators)

```
<table border="2">
<?php 

  for ($i=0; $i < 10 ; $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j=0; $j < 10 ; $j++) {
         echo "<td>", ($i==$j)? 1 : 0 ,"</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
  }
 ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Me anoto lo de los operadores ternarios, seguro que me va a ser muy útil. No conocía ese tuco

Answer (score 1):

Eso es sencillo solo tienes que usar dos ciclos repetitivos, para obtener la diagonal comparas `i == j` y colocas ceros, de lo contrario colocas unos

```
<?php
$tabla = "<table border='1'>";
$tabla .= "<tbody>";
for($i = 0; $i<10;$i++){
    $tabla .= "<tr>";
    for($j = 0; $j<10;$j++){
        if($i == $j){
            $tabla .= "<td>";
            $tabla .= "1";
            $tabla .= "</td>";
        }else{
            $tabla .= "<td>";
            $tabla .= "0";
            $tabla .= "</td>";
        }

    }
    $tabla .= "</tr>";
}
$tabla .= "</tbody>";
$tabla .= "</table>";

echo $tabla;
?>
```

El codigo anterior es sin usar bases de datos.

Comment: El .= qué significa?